# Cypress & Typescript - "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders" when using import.meta

Tags: typescript, vue.js, cypress, vite

I'm using Vue (although i don't think it's actually relevant), Vite, Cypress, and TypeScript.

one of my files, `foo.ts` happens to access `import.meta.url`:

```js
// src/foo.ts
export const FOO = import.meta.url;
```

In my real code it uses import.meta.url to contrive the path to a file in the 'public' directory. Hard-coding "/path/to/whatever.json" works in prod but doesn't work in cypress component tests which is why i have to use import.meta.url.

foo.ts works fine when imported by the web app and from component tests; problem is only when i also try to access it from cypress e2e test code.

```js
// cypress/e2e/example.cy.ts
import { FOO } from "../../src/foo"; // (also, how do i get the '@' prefix to work?)
describe('My First Test', () => {
  it('visits the app root url', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.contains('h1', 'You did it!')
  })
})
```

*EDIT: turns out foo.ts is unnecessary; you can just put `cy.log(import.meta.url)` in example.cy.ts*

when running example.cy.ts, i get this error:

[image]

I'm using more or less the default config provided by `yarn create vue`, and this can happen without any changes to that config.

<s>Repo which reproduces the issue: [https://gitlab.com/SIGSTACKFAULT~~/so-76317770](https://gitlab.com/SIGSTACKFAULT%7E%7E/so-76317770)</s>

- <s>`npm install`</s>
- <s>`npm run build`</s>
- <s>`npm run test:e2e:dev` -> end-to-end -> either browser</s>

---

### *EDIT*

that repo doesn't actually reproduce the error! but does happen on my original copy of the repo and if you create it by hand, somehow? despite package-lock.json existing; using `npm ci` instead doesn't help

this seems to reproduce it:

```
$> yarn create vue
✔ Project name: … vue-project
✔ Add TypeScript? … Yes
✔ Add JSX Support? … No
✔ Add Vue Router for Single Page Application development? … No
✔ Add Pinia for state management? … No
✔ Add Vitest for Unit Testing? … No
✔ Add an End-to-End Testing Solution? › Cypress
✔ Add ESLint for code quality? … No
$> cd vue-project
$> yarn
```

edit cypress/e2e/example.cy.ts:

```
// https://on.cypress.io/api

describe('My First Test', () => {
  it('visits the app root url', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.contains('h1', 'You did it!')
    cy.log(import.meta.url) // add this line
  })
})
```

**`yarn run test:e2e:dev`** -> Either Browser -> example.cy.ts

---

**alternatively:**
is there a way to access files in the public directory (in prod they're put at the web root) which works in prod, dev, *and* Cypress component testing?

*EDIT2:* I think I [XY](https://xyproblem.info/)'d myself with this

Comment: I didn't get the error - followed your instruction but using yarn instead of npm.

Comment: The other weird thing is your error is thrown from webpack, but the app uses vite. Aren't they supposed to be alternates?

Comment: @LolaIchingbola my hypothesis is that Cypress might use Webpack internally, but i haven't confirmed.

Comment: ...and it's spontaneously started working with npm too?

Comment: it doesn't happen if i clone the repo, but it still happens on my actual project and my original copy of the repo?

Comment: ran `npm update` in my project and it didn't help so it's not like the bug was fixed in the last few days

Comment: Yes- agree about the webpack error coming from Cypress. Will take a look at your revisions.

Comment: I take your edit to mean "that repo doesn't actually **error**! but does **error** on my original copy...".

Comment: > how do i get the '@' prefix to work?

Add this to your Cypress `tsconfig.json`: `"baseUrl": "./cypress",
    "paths": {
      "@support/*": ["support/*"],
      "@fixtures/*": ["fixtures/*"]
    }`

Change the `baseUrl` to your needs.

Comment: @LolaIchingbola yep; fixed

Comment: @DarkoRiđić I meant the shortcut to the `src` directory which ships by default with `create-vue`